# TreeView CheckBoxes=true and ShowNodeToolTips=true GDI objects leak

Tags: c#, winforms, memory-leaks, treeview, tooltip

TreeView leaks resource (2 DC handles and 2 Bitmap handles) when TreeView CheckBoxes=true because of a bug, and I dealt with it:

```
public class TreeViewCustom : TreeView
{
    public new bool CheckBoxes
    {
        get
        {
            return base.CheckBoxes;
        }
        set
        {
            if (base.CheckBoxes == false)
            {
                base.CheckBoxes = true;

                IntPtr handle = SendMessage(this.Handle, TVM_GETIMAGELIST, new IntPtr(TVSIL_STATE), IntPtr.Zero);
                if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
                    _checkboxImageList = handle;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The handle to the state ImageList
    /// </summary>
    private IntPtr _checkboxImageList = IntPtr.Zero;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x203) // double click
            m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
        else
            base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left || e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            Focus();
            SelectedNode = GetNodeAt(e.X, e.Y);
        }
    }

    [DllImport("comctl32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern bool ImageList_Destroy(IntPtr hImageList);

    [DllImport("comctl32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern bool ImageList_RemoveAll(IntPtr hImageList);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern System.IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg,
    IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    const uint TV_FIRST = 0x1100;
    const uint TVM_GETIMAGELIST = TV_FIRST + 8;
    const int TVSIL_NORMAL = 0;
    const int TVSIL_STATE = 2;

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_checkboxImageList != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                ImageList_Destroy(_checkboxImageList);
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
            this.DestroyHandle();
        }

        else base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

And everything is OK, except when treeview.ShowNodeToolTips is set to true, then the resources still leak, even with the fix. I think the tooltip is a problem (ToolTips also leak handles if you don't dispose of them properly)

**EDIT:**

(Why the leak happens when CheckBoxes = true)

When CheckBoxes is set to true, the style is set to the TreeView, and it can be done only once. This causes an CheckBoxImageList to be created. The list contains 2 bitmaps: the checked and unchecked box, every object in the list has a DC handle and a BITMAP handle (that's why 4 handles are leaked for each instance). When the TreeView is disposed, the list of images isn't destroyed, hence the leak.

(Why the leak happens when ShowNodeToolTips=true - my suspicions, http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/fx/src/WinForms/Managed/System/WinForms/TreeView@cs/2/TreeView@cs)

The TootTip holds the reference to the control, if the ToolTip is not disposed, the control stays in the memory too. When ShowNodeToolTips = true, the ToolTip is created and associated with the TreeView, and it isn't disposed when TreeView is disposed.

**The code I use for testing:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form_Tv form = new Form_Tv();
            form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent; ;
            form.ShowDialog();

            form.Dispose();
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }

public partial class Form_Tv : Form
    {
        public Form_Tv()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                TreeViewCustom tv = new TreeViewCustom();
                tv.CheckBoxes = true;
                tv.ShowNodeToolTips = true;
                this.Controls.Add(tv);
            }

            this.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(Form_Tv_FormClosed);
            this.ControlRemoved += new ControlEventHandler(Form_Tv_ControlRemoved);
        }

        void Form_Tv_ControlRemoved(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Control.Dispose();
        }

        void Form_Tv_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Controls.Clear();
        }
    }
```

Test results (Windows 7):

Form1 is the main form of the application. After it's shown:

> DC: 7 Bitmap: 3

After Form_Tv is shown:

> DC: 409   Bitmap: 405

After Form_Tv is closed:

> DC: 209   Bitmap: 205

**My question:**

How can I get a hold of the ToolTip that is set for the TreeView when ShowNodeToolTips is set to true, and how can I properly dispose of it?

Comment: This is an XY Problem.  A handle leak in TreeView is very unlikely, it is a native Windows control that is used in a *lot* of programs.  You are the first user I've seen that reports a leak.  A standard Winforms bug is to not call the Dispose() method of a control after removing it from the parent's Controls collection.  Very easy to get wrong, it leaks the native resources used by the control forever.

Comment: @HansPassant I call the dispose when it's due (TableLayoutPanel & FlowLayoutPanel OnControlRemoved, after form.ShowDialog etc) TreeView leaks handles when CheckBoxes=true because of .net bug, and it was reported before - that's how I have a partial solution. It leaks, try it yourself (you can check it easily using e.g this http://thesz.diecru.eu/content/bear.php). The leak isn't a problem unless you use the TreeView a lot, and I do.

Comment: I already checked, creating and disposing a TV in a loop ten thousand times.  Nothing, nada, zippo.  Windows 8.1

Comment: @HansPassant I have Windows 7, I'd have to test it on Windows 8